# DbUpdateException when seeding data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to populate my code first database with an admin user account for myself so that I can access the system.

To do this, I'm calling a `Seed` method in my Global.asax file which does the following:

```
    public void Seed()
    {
        if (!Roles.Any())
        {
            List<Role> roles = new List<Role>
            {
                new Role { RoleName = "Admin" },
                new Role { RoleName = "User" }
            };
            foreach (Role r in roles)
            {
                Roles.Add(r);
            }
            SaveChanges();
        }
        if (!Users.Any())
        {
            User u = new User();
            u.EmailAddress = "my@email.address";
            u.Username = "ortund";
            u.Password = Hashing.CreateHash("p455W0rd");
            u.Role = Roles.Single(r => r.RoleName == "Admin");

            Users.Add(u);
            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

User and Role are defined as follows:

```
namespace Logan.Web.Objects
{
    public class User : LoganBaseObject<User>
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Username = String.Empty;
            EmailAddress = String.Empty;
            Password = String.Empty;
            Biography = String.Empty;
            Articles = new List<Article>();
        }
    }
}
    public class Role : LoganBaseObject<Role>
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Role()
        {
            RoleName = String.Empty;
            Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }
}

namespace Logan.Web.DBContext
{
    public class RoleDBContext : LoganDBBaseObject<Role>
    {
        private static WebDBContext db = new WebDBContext();

        public RoleDBContext()
            : base()
        {
            Property(p => p.RoleName)
                .HasColumnName("sRoleName")
                .IsRequired();

            HasMany(m => m.Users)
                .WithRequired();

            ToTable("Roles");
        }
    }

    public class UserDBContext : LoganDBBaseObject<User>
    {
        private static WebDBContext db = new WebDBContext();

        public UserDBContext()
            : base()
        {
            Property(p => p.Username)
                .HasColumnName("sUsername")
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(p => p.EmailAddress)
                .HasColumnName("sEmailAddress")
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(p => p.Password)
                .HasColumnName("sPassword")
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(p => p.Biography)
                .HasColumnName("sBiography")
                .HasColumnType("text");

            HasRequired(r => r.Role)
                .WithMany(m => m.Users)
                .Map(x => x.MapKey("fkRoleID"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            Property(p => p.CreateDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime");

            ToTable("Users");

        }
    }
}
```

When the `Seed` method above gets to SaveChanges(), I get the following error:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Obviously this has something to do with the relationships that are being constructed here, but I don't actually know what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone recommend a solution and/or explain what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of the structure that is genergated. The PKey field is added from `LoganBaseObject<T>`:

[image: code-first database diagram]

Comment: Not at all. I even tried explicitly adding a UserId property to the User class with a [Key] data annotation as well as the same for Role class

Comment: HasMany(m => m.Users).WithRequired();

You didn't supply a user to the role. which causes the exception.

Comment: @EdwinvanVliet removing that hasn't made any difference. I'm not sure what sort of relationship it should be. A user can only have 1 role but many users can have the same role.

Comment: I've updated the question to add in a screenshot of the database structure generated by the above code

Comment: Could you try adding the user first to the database. than add new Roles to that user. and then SaveChanges().

Answer (score 0):

I really need to learn to include absolutely all the information from the tables.

I had some datetime columns in the User table for which I wasn't supplying values in the `Seed` method. See here:

```
public class User : LoganBaseObject<User>
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public bool PasswordReset { get; set; }
    public string PasswordResetKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResetExpiry { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

I still don't get why missing values would produce this error about foreign keys, but supplying values in the Seed method fixed the problem.